# Update field value through reverse relationship. Django REST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using `djangorestframework-simplejwt` for authentication. My use case requires me to use OTP instead of passwords.

To store OTPs, I have created the following model:

```
class OneTimePassword(models.Model):
    otp = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    country_code = models.IntegerField(default=91, max_length=3)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.email},{self.mobile}"
```

My plan is:

1. POST `mobile` to `/api/generate_otp/` endpoint
2. Inside the view for this endpoint, a new OTP is generated and stored at `OneTimePassword` model. (the user is determined from mobile number)
3. At the `api/token/obtain/` endpoint, OTP and mobile number is posted.
4. If OTP matches the value stored in the OTP model, then JWT token is returned.

I am facing difficulty in **step 2**, i.e. I am not able to update the value of OTP in OneTimePassword Model through the user.

I have tried the following approach:

```
class GenerateOTPMobileView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()

    def post(self, request,):
        mobile = request.data.get("mobile")
        user = User.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
        random_otp = randint(10000, 99999)
        if user:
            user.onetimepassword_set.otp = random_otp   # This is not working
            ...
            # send OTP through third party API
            ...
            return Response({"success": "OTP sent to mobile number"},)
        else:
            return Response({"error": "Wrong Credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: It's probably working just fine, but are you saving the user? Wait, you're assigning to a reverse relation...If this is Django 2 it is silently ignored. Use [these methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: @Melvyn I'm not sure how to so that. Also, I'm not creating a new user but just updating the OTP value

Comment: @Melvyn any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set a property on the many side of a relationship and it doesn't work that way. Basically, you're just setting a property on the manager and the manager just like any other well behaved python object, will just set this property on itself - but it doesn't do anything useful.

Instead, you should either [`create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create) a new OTP or `update()` a specific OTP.

Remember your data model looks like this:

```
user:
   - otp1
   - otp2
   - otp3
```

etc.

So there is not "one OTP for one user". For that you need a OneToOneField.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up converting it to an OneToOneField and used the update_or_create() method.